# Using "project.setProperty" vs a regular variable in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What is the difference between these two approaches in a Gradle [Kotlin build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)?
Specifically, I wanted to know what is the advantage (if any) of using `setProperty()` method?

```
val myMainClass = "MainClass"
```

vs

```
setProperty("myMainClass", "MainClass") // equivalent to project.setProperty(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know what is the advantage (if any) of using `setProperty()` method?

That is entirely dependent on your use case/what you're trying to achieve.

The first approach is not Gradle specific in any means. You are defining a read-only variable named `myMainClass`. This is just basic Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables

The second approach defining/setting a property on the current project. With this approach, wherever you have access to `project`, you can reference the property via `property("myMainClass")` or `project.property("myMainClass")`

`setProperty` and `project.setProperty` achieve the same outcome. In a Gradle build script, `this` refers to the `project` instance, which is why you can do `setProperty`, `file`, `uri`, `ant`, and so on.